# How to communicate between pods in same service in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, kubernetes, networking

I am wondering what the best way is to communicate between pods in the same service - in Kubernetes. I would like to avoid configuration in Kubernetes to achieve this, since this functionality would be a part of an open source library, and I want to make it as easy as possible to adopt it. The library will be written in Java to start with.

Short about the use-case is that I want to update state in all pods belonging to the same service when something happens in one of them. Using an external service to keep state (like a database) to achieve this is not an option for me.

I would prefer event-based communication between the pods, websocket-based or possibly http based. As pods can be removed and added to the same service, I might need a way to keep track of this as well.

I have been looking at https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java - and it feels like I should be able to solve this using that library. Kubernetes injects this **hostname** environment variable automatically, and it should be possible to look up the service using it and somehow list all the other pods in the service. It also seems to offer listener functionality for when a pod is added/deleted/updated, and functionality to establish websockets between pods.

It would be great if this could be achieved without using any 3rd party library like the above one, although I am not sure if it's possible. I am looking for advice on how to approach this the best way.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The architecture sounds like it is begging for data consistency and scalability issues. Is it really necessary to propagate updates to all pods?

Comment: @Turing85 data consistency issues I can also see happening, it is to be expected although it should be rare. Scalability issues might arise depending on what the solution is, but I feel like it could be avoided. For my use-case I need to propagate the update to all pods yeah.

Comment: All solutions that come to my mind (aside from interacting with the kubernetes API and getting a list of all pod names under a service, then sending the information to those services) would require a 3rd party component (a database, redis, messaging system, ...).

Comment: In terms of dicsovering other pods from within a pod, you can definitely use kubernetes api to discover other pods in the same deployment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/ For keeping states in-sync between pods, it is depedent on your requirement. However, most systems like zookeeper/etcd cluster will use a distributed consensus protocol to achieve this and I would advise not to built one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be a clear approach. It can limit ability to scale out your app, but you won't need any external libraries, to communicate with Kube-API.

**Create a headless service**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services

Next to your normal `ClisterIP`, create a headless service. It is used for direct pod communication, not like classic `CLusterIP` which acts like a loadbalancer. When you associate headless service with your deployment, doing an `nslookup` on that service address will return list of IP Addresses of pods from it.

So your app can make a dns lookup, obtain the ip addresses of other pods, and use it to sync it state.

You have to consider how it will work on high workload, and what will happen if you want to scale up or scale down. Will it query for other pods only on init ? When the pods pool will be updated? From what I see a good solution to this would be implementing some type of cache, such as Redis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While the solution is good, the downside with it in my case is that I will force everyone that uses my library to do this setup. In the end, I ended up with using the kubernetes API (through the external java library that integrates with it) to fetch all other pods in the same deployment, and using the built in functionality to subscribe to pod updated/added/removed events to maintain the list of the other pods.